# Is there an age requirement for Ingress?

Tags: ingress

I have heard rumors about one needing to be 18+ to play Ingress. Therefore, I have two questions.

1. Is it true that one must be 18 or older to play this game?
2. What would happen if someone below the age of 18 were to play this game?

Comment: This did used to be the case, but the Ingress terms of service were recently changed.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Their [terms](http://www.ingress.com/terms) do not require you to be over 18.

Answer (score 2):

Their terms used to require players be aged 18 or older, however this was rarely enforced.

A recent change to the terms removed that clause, and it is now the Google default of 13.